# Растянуть выпадающее при наведении меню по ширине 100%

Tags: html, css

есть header с nav, где при наведении выпадает список.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выделил красным блок с подменю, который выходит при наведении на пункты меню. Как расстянуть по всей ширине выпадающий блок? Header по высоте расширяется при наведении на меню.

```
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">Пункт 1</a>
                <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                  <li class="row">
                    <ul class="mega-col">
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                  </li>
                </ul>        
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Пункт 2</a>
                <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                  <li class="row">
                    <ul class="mega-col">
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>        
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Пункт 3</a>
                <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                  <li class="row">
                    <ul class="mega-col">
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>        
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Пункт 4</a>
                <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                  <li class="row">
                    <ul class="mega-col">
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>        
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">Пункт 5</a>
                <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                  <li class="row">
                    <ul class="mega-col">
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Подпункт 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>        
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

        
    </header>
</div>
```

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
 

ul[class],
ol[class] {
  list-style: none;
}
 

a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}
 

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
 

article > * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
 

input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}
 

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  * {
    animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
  }
}

.wrap {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'M PLUS 1p', sans-serif;
    
}

.header {
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 198px;
    max-height: 288px;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;

    .logo {
        background: url(./img/logo.png);
        width: 42px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-right: 213px;
    }
}



*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff
}


nav {
    float: right;
}

nav>ul {
    float: left;
    position: relative
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left
}

nav .dropdown {
    position: relative
}

nav li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 35px
}

nav li a:hover {
    background: #2C3E50
}

nav li ul {
    display: none
}

nav li:hover ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    background: #000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav li li {
    float: none
}

nav .dropdown ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #34495e
}

nav .dropdown li {
    white-space: nowrap
}

nav .dropdown li a {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 200px
}

nav .mega-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 35px;
    
}

nav li li a {
    float: none;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 13px
}

nav li li a:hover {
    background: #bdc3c7;
    background: #FAFBFB
}

.mega-col {
    width: 25%;
    float: left
}

#menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: none
}

#menu-icon span {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .1s
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
    nav>ul>li>a {
        padding: 35px 15px
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    nav {
        display: block!important
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    nav {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow-y: scroll
    }
    #menu-icon {
        display: inline;
        top: 45px;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    #menu-icon.active .first {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        margin-top: 10px
    }
    #menu-icon.active .second {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
        position: relative;
        top: -9px;
    }
    #menu-icon.active .third {
        display: none
    }
    .search {
        float: none
    }
    .search input {
        width: 100%
    }
    nav {
        padding: 10px
    }
    nav ul {
        float: none
    }
    nav li {
        float: none
    }
    nav ul li a {
        float: none;
        padding: 8px;
        display: block
    }
    #header nav ul ul {
        display: block;
        position: static;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        padding: 0
    }
    #header nav a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 8px
    }
    #header nav a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        border-radius: 3px
    }
    #header nav ul li li a:before {
        content: "- "
    }
    .mega-col {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я убрал `position: relative` у родителей dropmenu и добавил `position: relative` для .header

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

ul[class],
ol[class] {
    list-style: none;
}

.wrap {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'M PLUS 1p', sans-serif;
    
}

.header {
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 198px;
    max-height: 288px;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav>ul {
    float: left;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left
}

nav .dropdown {
    position: relative
}

nav li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 35px
}

nav li a:hover {
    background: #2C3E50
}

nav li ul {
    display: none
}

nav li:hover ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f50;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li li {
    float: none
}

nav .dropdown ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #34495e
}

nav .dropdown li {
    white-space: nowrap
}

nav .dropdown li a {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 200px
}

nav .mega-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 35px;
    
}

nav li li a {
    float: none;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 13px
}

nav li li a:hover {
    background: #bdc3c7;
    background: #FAFBFB
}

.mega-col {
    width: 25%;
    float: left
}

#menu-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: none
}

#menu-icon span {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .1s
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
        </div>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Пункт 1</a>
                    <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                        <li class="row">
                            <ul class="mega-col">
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Пункт 2</a>
                    <ul class="mega-dropdown">
                        <li class="row">
                            <ul class="mega-col">
                                <li><a href="#">Подпункт 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Подпункт 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Подпункт 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Подпункт 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    
    </header>
</div>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас освобожусь, буду тестить.